Interactive ggpubr with plotly and crosstalk
I have been looking for solutions about how to combine in R ggpubr with plotly and with crosstalk to render interactive plots (eg in non-shiny R- markdown).

I am glad to find a solution, and to share it with anyone interested...
It is quite simple and merely involves fortify().
Here is an example with boxplots - allowing also for filter_select
library(ggpubr)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

# add another numeric col
df=ToothGrowth %>% mutate(len2=len+rnorm(10))

g <- highlight_key(df ,~dose)


p1= g %>% fortify() %>% ggboxplot( x = "dose", y = "len",
 color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),  
  add = "jitter", shape = "dose") 

p2= g %>% fortify() %>% ggboxplot( x = "dose", y = "len2",
   color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),  
  add = "jitter", shape = "dose")
    
xx=highlight(subplot(ggplotly(p1),ggplotly(p2)), "plotly_click",selectize = F)


bscols(
  filter_select("id", "Select a dose", g, ~dose),
  xx,
  widths = c(12)
)

